# Woocommerce remove link on read more button for out of stock items

Tags: woocommerce

I cannot figure out how to remove the link to the single product page for an out of stock item in category. I have changed the "read more" to "sold" and want it to be a static message, so to speak, versus linking to the product detail. Can anyone help with this? I have searched for days and am php challenged :).

Thank you

Comment: It's not very clear what you need.
- Do you need to remove the AddToCart button for products out of stock (which shows ReadMore instead AddToCart)?

- Do you need to remove the reference to the product page from the product block (not just the button)? So you click the product and it wont go anywhere?
And also, what have you tried?, specifically.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I am using a grid plugin to show woocommerce products. The single-product shows in a lightbox instead of going to the normal single-product page. I do not want the "read more" link to take the user to the default single-products page. I have tried nothing, as I am not sure what/where to try. In the meantime, I have used numerous scripts to change the "read more" to "sold", which works visually, except, it messes with the "add to cart" function on items in stock. Is added to cart BUT there is no indication that it's been added. Clear as mud :)? Thank you!

Comment: Again, it's not that clear. Let's see if we can get visual with this:  
Check this demo page http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/product-category/men/  
If I get you right, you have a plugin similar to the one that shows the Quick View on hover, and on click pops a lightbox.  
Now if I follow, you want the product out of stock (the one in the middle, last row) to be "link-less" or "href-less" :p so it won't go anywhere.  
It's like that???

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you!!! The grid I am using does not integrate well with Woocommerce, but I have not been able to find another that will allow product thumbnails to stay true to size, it is for artwork with variable sizes (some vertical, some horizontal.

Comment: I just bought the flatsome theme, good for the grid they offer, not so good for easy customization of woocommerce pages... it's always something! Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Hi, I think that is a great plugin, the PageBuilder is a cool feature (http://recordit.co/KwECGLtWfu).  Also, it's a good start to override some templates creating a child theme if you need more drastic changes.

Comment: Yes, I am using child theme for edits, but am having problems with a few not making the changes I need. Looks like they change/add woocommerce files to work with their theme. A very noce theme if one doesn't want it customized... So far, support is not so good. Thanks for your help.